# How can I remove the action bar from a dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-actionbar, styles

getActionBar().hide(); will crash cause getActionBar is null.
This does not work neither:

```
<style name="NoActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

This is my code:

```
  public static void popupWindow(final Context context,String title ,String desc,final CrudStateCallback back){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.ShowPopup);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.R.color.transparent));
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.sticky_layout);
    colourTitleBar(context, dialog);
    String sansproEL = "fonts/source_sans_pro_extraLight.ttf";
    String sansproL = "fonts/source_sans_pro_light.ttf";
    Typeface sansproL_TF = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), sansproL);
    Typeface sansproEL_TF = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), sansproEL);
    ((TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.popup_text)).setTypeface(sansproL_TF);
    ((TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.popup_text2)).setTypeface(sansproEL_TF);
    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.popup_text);
    TextView text2 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.popup_text2);
    RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.all_container);
    View.OnClickListener dismissList = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            if(back!= null)
                back.onResponse("");
        }
    };
    text.setText(title);
    text2.setText(desc);
    container.setOnClickListener(dismissList);
    PSLocationCenter.getInstance().instabug.setDialog(dialog);
    dialog.show();
    Handler han = new Handler();
    han.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                dialog.dismiss();
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.i("","error in popup window");
            }
            if(back!= null)
                back.onResponse("");
        }
    }, 3000);
}

  public static void colourTitleBar(Context context, Dialog dialog) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        dialog.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
    }
}
```

And my style:

```
<style name="ShowPopup">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/ShowPopupAnimation</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">0dp</item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar as a parent for your theme?

Comment: I'll get back with an answer when I get back at work on monday

Comment: Usage of *.NoActionBar theme results in no need to remove the ActionBar programmatically. This may or may not be a good solution in your case, based on the context of your project. You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try simply removing this line?

```
colourTitleBar(context, dialog);
```

Comment: I just added that. That will make the status bar disappear. That's why I added it.
Also the bars, both status and action we're invisible. Before updating to the latest SDK and Android Studio Version.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to remove the ActionBar or the Dialog's title bar? If the first you could try calling requestWindowFeature() on the Activity, not the Dialog. And before setContentView(), as mentioned.

Comment: I need to remove the actionBar but just from the dialogue, so it will remain in the activity

Comment: Can't you just hide it with getActivity().getActionbar().hide() or getSupportActionBar().hide() ..., then on dismiss of the dialog get it back with show()?